# How to get ALAssetURL from string Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, alassetslibrary

I am saving ALAssetURL as a string inside an array.  I would like to read back these strings as URLs.  How do I do this in Swift?

```
assetLib.writeImage(toSavedPhotosAlbum: imageToSave.cgImage, orientation: ALAssetOrientation(rawValue: imageToSave.imageOrientation.rawValue)!, completionBlock: {(url,error) -> Void in
                        // Saving url as string inside urlArray, how do I get url from these strings later?
                        urlArray.append(url?.absoluteString)
```

I need to save as string because I am saving the url array inside user defaults.

Comment: You can use KeyedArchiver to save your `[URL]` as data and KeyedUnarchiever to load the data and cast it back to `[URL]`. Note that converting it to data allows you to save it also to a file instead of UserDefaults

Comment: You really want to keep saving is as string using the property `url.absoluteString` you will need to use the `URL(string:)` initializer. The `URL(fileURLwithPath:)` wouldn't work. To use the `URL(fileURLwithPath:)`  initializer you need to save the `url.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't the method `URL(string: <url>)` do the trick?

Comment: it is not a method it is a initializer

Comment: yeah, but he wants the URL back, right? Why not initialize one with this initializer? Am I missing something?